# Unable to get last friday date in PST time in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am trying to getting last friday date PST time, i am getting 15-11-2018,
Here is my code,

```
public function getPSTCurrentTime($time=null) {
    $dateTime = new \DateTime($time, (new \DateTimeZone('UTC')));  // get current time as UTC/GMT timezone
    $dateTime->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('PST'));            // convert time as PST timezone
    return $dateTime;
}

$date = new getPSTCurrentTime('last friday')->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');
```

The output i am getting was 15-11-2018, But i am expecting output was 16-11-2018

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$pst = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
$last_friday = new DateTime('last friday', $pst); 
echo $last_friday->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // "2018-11-16 00:00:00"
```

After Comment:

To get the date based on the current timezone, then use [date_default_timezone_get](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php)

```
$current_timezone = new DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get());
$last_friday = new DateTime('last friday', $current_timezone);
```

Output:

> 2018-11-16 00:00:00

Comment: I don't to put any Datetimezone, here, the user may login from any where

Comment: i am converting UTC time zone to PST timezone,

Comment: What is your actual requirement? There is a way if you want to take dates based on the timezone and there is no need to convert to `UTC` first

Comment: I am working from india, and my client was america, The difference between time 8 hours between UTC and PST, any user can login according to their time, so i am trying to convert UTC to PST, your method was wrong